# Converting list of list of strings into list of list of integers

Tags: python, list

listX = [['0,0,0,3,0,4,0,3'], ['0,0,0,0,0,3,0,7'], ['0,0,1,0,0,5,0,4'], ['0,0,0,1,3,1,0,5'], ['1,1,1,0,0,0,2,5'], ['0,0,0,1,1,5,0,3'], ['0,0,0,5,3,0,0,2']]

I need it to output

[[0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 7], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4], [0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 5], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 5, 0, 3], [0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 2]]

when I use listX = [[int(float(o)) for o in p] for p in listX] I get ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0,0,0,3,0,4,0,3'

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following list comprehension:

```
output = [[int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+', y[0])] for y in listX]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 7],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4], [0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 5],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 5, 0, 3],
 [0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 2]]
```

This uses a nested list comprehension.  The outer comprehension feeds one-element CSV integer strings into the inner comprehension.  The inner list comprehension uses `re.findall` to find integers inside the CSV list, one at a time.

Comment: Thank you so much, this does indeed work. Can you explain how exactly it works?
this part " re.findall(r'\d+', y[0])] "

Comment: I have added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to firs split every string you have `listX[i].split(",")` and then apply the casting

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of lists with more than a single item you could try the following (nested) list comprehension:

```
output = [list(map(int, y.split(','))) for x in listX for y in x]
```

If know your lists contain only a single item, all you'll need is:

```
output = [list(map(int, x[0].split(','))) for x in listX]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your input is

```
[['0,0,0,3,0,4,0,3'], ['0,0,0,0,0,3,0,7'], 
 ['0,0,1,0,0,5,0,4'], ['0,0,0,1,3,1,0,5'], 
 ['1,1,1,0,0,0,2,5'], ['0,0,0,1,1,5,0,3'], 
 ['0,0,0,5,3,0,0,2']]
```

Let us start off by splitting it at `,` using the split method and dumping the whole content into a temporary array say `x`. The code is as follows-

```
x=[]
[[x.append(j.split(",")) for j in i] for i in input]
print(x)
```

The `print(x)` statement is used solely for debugging & understanding how that part of my code works. You can remove it as seen fit. Now we perform the conversion of lists of strings to lists of integers and store it in the variable say 'y'. The code is as follows -

```
y = [[int(j) for j in i] for i in x]
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

My in-place solution:

```
listX = list(map(lambda x: list(int(y) for y in x[0].split(',')), listX))
```